# WebCollector Could not parse query Java

Tags: java, parsing, token

```
    public Links visitAndGetNextLinks(Page page) {
        String url = page.getUrl();

        if (Pattern.matches("http://bbs.gter.net/forum-1033-.*", url)) {
            Links nextLinks=new Links();


            nextLinks.addAllFromDocument(page.getDoc(),"http://bbs.gter.net/thread.*");
            System.out.println(nextLinks+"\n");
            return nextLinks;
        }else{


            byte[] content=page.getContent();
            try {
                FileUtils.writeFileWithParent("/Users/gary/Dropbox/hooom/program/html"+id.incrementAndGet()+".txt", content);
                System.out.println("save page "+page.getUrl());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

After running the above code, this is what I've got...

"Could not parse query 'http://bbs.gter.net/thread.*': unexpected token at '://bbs.gter.net/thread.*'"

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
RegexRule regexRule = new RegexRule();

{
    regexRule.addRule("http://bbs.gter.net/thread.*");
}

public Links visitAndGetNextLinks(Page page) {
    String url = page.getUrl();

    if (Pattern.matches("http://bbs.gter.net/forum-1033-.*", url)) {
        Links nextLinks=new Links();


        nextLinks.addAllFromDocument(page.getDoc(),regexRule);
        System.out.println(nextLinks+"\n");
        return nextLinks;
    }else{


        byte[] content=page.getContent();
        try {
            FileUtils.writeFileWithParent("/Users/gary/Dropbox/hooom/program/html"+id.incrementAndGet()+".txt", content);
            System.out.println("save page "+page.getUrl());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```